# Spinner Scrollbar inset or padding

Tags: java, android

I'm looking to change the style of the scrollbar in my spinner popup view. But changing properties in the xml doesn't do anything to the popup as it's a different view.

[image]

```xml
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/countrySpinner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:popupBackground="@drawable/spinner_dropdown_background"
        android:popupElevation="4dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/PopupTheme"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/citySpinner"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.8" />
```

This is the style of my spinner. As it's clear, the scrollbar is appearing on top of the corners of the spinner which make it look very off.

Is there anyway to change the style of the scrollbar? Make it more round like the corners. Or at least remove it entirely.

**Edit :** I managed to remove it from styles. Would still like if there was a way to customize it

Comment: Could you please post your xml file

Answer (score 0):

`Spinner` does not have a scrollbar.The popup shown by spinner has a `scrollbar`. So you need to change the properties of the `ListView` shown by spinner. But `ListView` itself is not exposed by Spinner by any public methods.

But If you are going to create a custom Spinner, i believe it is easier to implement the whole popup to suit your needs than using reflection.

check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19812302/spinners-scrollbar-style) for more explanation