# Spinner items are cut off at top if spinner is placed on a dialog

Tags: android, dialog, spinner

I placed a spinner on a dialog. When I want to select an item and the item list is shown below the spinner, everything is fine and I can scroll through the items. But if the item list is shown above the spinner, the item list is cut off and I cannot scroll:

[image: Item list is cut off]

It looks like the system does not identify, that the item list above the dialog is not visible and therefore does not show the scrollbars.

My spinner definition looks like this:

```
            <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spnnrValue"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
```

This is how I define the dialog:

```
        dialogColorPickerExtended = new Dialog(Base.getMainActivity(), R.style.full_screen_dialog);
    dialogColorPickerExtended.setCancelable(true);
    dialogColorPickerExtended.setContentView(R.layout.template_color_picker_extended);
    if (dialogColorPickerExtended.getWindow() != null)
        dialogColorPickerExtended.getWindow().getAttributes().width = (int) (GUIManager.getScreenWidth() * 0.9f);
```

Do you have any idea, how I can show the complete item list?

Answer (score 0):

You might not be able to show it all at once, but adding a scrollbar to the spinner itself may be a solution.  Visit this page, you might be able to solve this problem with an overall functionality improvement by adding a scrollbar to your spinner.

[Spinner's scrollbar style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19812302)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it does not work - the list view is always null...