# Android Spinner Contains Very Long Text

Tags: java, android, scroll, dropdown

I Have a Spinner(Dropdown) that holds 50 rows in it, as well contains Approximately more than 160 characters in every row, the issue is prefix till 20 characters is same for all, my question is that how can i make this spinner vertically scrollable (default) and Horizontally as well.

so that i can see whole the value of the rows.

Comment: Have you made custom layout for Spinner?

Comment: @farhana no i don't have, i have used android's default layout for spinner

Comment: made custom layout and use custom spinner adapter where you can set scroll as you want

Comment: Isn't a bad design? Although by combination of popupwindow and recyclerView you can do this.

Comment: please check this link, it is helpful for you  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014485/cant-make-spinners-scrollbar-always-visible-android/12644532#12644532

Answer (score 1):

Create custom Layout with TextView Horizontally Scrollabal like below

custom_spinner.xml

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Scrollable Text" 
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Then set custom Layout to your Adapter class (may be custom or any other like ArrayAdapter)

```
ArrayAdapter your_Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_spinner,your_array);
your_spinner.setAdapter(your_Adapter );
```