# How to show spinner with limited number of item in drop down?

Tags: android, layout, drop-down-menu

I want to use spinner in my Activity in android application.

My requirement is, I want to show only 6 items in drop down list at one time if their are more that 6 items then scroll bar should be visible. How to achieve this requirement.

Below is the sample code I am trying for UI in android activity.xml.

```xml
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:dropDownVerticalOffset="40dp"
    android:forceHasOverlappingRendering="false" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android limit the no of items displayed in a spinner's dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238513/android-limit-the-no-of-items-displayed-in-a-spinners-dropdown-list)

Comment: Spinners in Android doesn't have a Scrollbar, the scrollbar exist within the listView maintained inside the Spinner, and has no public access. There's a run-time way to override it in the link below .. Resource: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12644532/2128327

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't make spinner's scrollbar always visible (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014485/cant-make-spinners-scrollbar-always-visible-android)

Answer (score 0):

you can visit this link for more details 
[How to limit the height of Spinner drop down view in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20597584/how-to-limit-the-height-of-spinner-drop-down-view-in-android)

You can use this awesome library *MaterialSpinner* that will do all the hard work for you.

Download: implementation 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.3.1'

inside your xml file.

```
    <com.jaredrummler.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:ms_dropdown_max_height="400dp"/>
```

set height using `app:ms_dropdown_max_height="400dp"`